# I can't figure out what I might be missing or what's wrong with my API call

Tags: php

I have created an API endpoint with PHP + MySQL. Once I hit it I query my database which has 3 tables:

`spec`: which contain a list with name, address, and city
`spece`: which contains a list with the possible specialities to have
`specspec`: which basically handles the relationship that 1 option might have multiple specialities. So you find things like 1, 2; 1,3; 1,5; 2, 1; etc. (basically where the first number is the id of the option and the second number the id of the speciality)

In order to retrieve this, I have this SQL query in the PHP:

```
// create a new PDO object to connect to the database
$pdo = new PDO(<info_goes_here>);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT e.nombre AS especialista_nombre, e.telefono, esp.nombre AS especialidad_nombre
    FROM spec e
    JOIN specspec ee ON e.id = ee.especialista_id
    JOIN especialidades esp ON ee.especialidad_id = esp.id
    WHERE e.city = :city AND e.state = :state
");
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $city);
$stmt->bindParam(':state', $state);
$stmt->execute();

// fetch the results as an associative array
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// check if any options were found
if ($result) {
    // return a JSON response with the options' data
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'options' => $result));
    exit;
}
```

However when I hit this endpoint, I do get a 200 response (no error on the server either) but the message body is empty and I have no idea why... any help of what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on verbose debug:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdo = new PDO(<info_goes_here>);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then something like

```
try {
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

because right now your 200 ok and no body is because $result is false. But false isn't enough information to know what's wrong.